# MySQL query returning wrong values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this MySQL query where I want to fetch the right artists after the relevant letter has been clicked on the frontend. Now there are also artists beginning with a number so I want to exclude them. Even though, right now the artists which begin with a number gets displayed no matter what, so I assume my MySQL query is wrong.

```
$sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM artists WHERE formated_name LIKE '".$letter."%' OR formated_name LIKE '0%' OR formated_name LIKE '1%' OR formated_name LIKE '2%' 
            OR formated_name LIKE '3%' OR formated_name LIKE '4%' OR formated_name LIKE '5%' OR formated_name LIKE '6%' OR formated_name LIKE '7%'
            OR formated_name LIKE '8%' OR formated_name LIKE '9%' OR formated_name LIKE '#%'";
```

Can someone help me out here? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM artists 
WHERE formated_name LIKE '".$letter."%' 
AND LEFT(formated_name, 1) NOT IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')";
```

Comment: Hmm ok, but `$letter` could also be a number, so your suggestion is not almost usable but maybe I have to reconsider my way of doing the function...

Comment: @SHT I understood you totally want to exclude numbers, if you don't want to, then Graham's solution is the one that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM artists 
WHERE formated_name LIKE '".$letter."%'
```

This will only return results that start with your letter.

Comment: thought about that, but what if the user actually enters a number

Comment: Depends how you want to handle a number... do you want an error message or just nothing returned?  If you want an error message you might as well handle the number exception before sending it to MySQL anyway.  Although I'm a bit confused... if you have artists that start with numbers, why wouldn't you want users to ever be able to query them?

Comment: as Andrew says do it before sending the query - it will make it a nicer experience for the user if you do client side validation as well as server side validation - 'oops - letters only please'